# Perforce submission from command line with description & interactive prompt

Tags: command-line, submit, perforce, submission

I am trying to automate the submission of the default changelist in perforce after making changes  to a file and need to have a command line way to execute submission to perforce while providing a description as well as bypass the interactive prompt.

when I submit using the following command

```
p4 -p $perforce_server -u $user submit -d "Do you want to submit [yes/no]: yes"
```

The submission works but there is no description for the submitted change list in perforce.

Now if I try the below command

```
p4 -p $perforce_server -u $user submit -d "My newly modified file...  Do you want to submit [yes/no]: yes"
```

I get an error as the interactive prompt does not match.

How do I add a description to the changelist and also bypass the perforce interactive prompt in a single command.

I can do the submission with a description in the P4 GUI in a format as shown below and it works with the comment as follows.

```
"My newly modified file
...
Do you want to submit [yes/no]: yes"
```

Can you let me know how the abive can be performed via command line as well. Appreciate all you experienced P4 users input on this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no interactive prompt in Perforce if you do:

```
p4 submit -d "My newly modified file"
```

If you're getting a prompt when you run that command, that's some other tooling (are you running p4 via some kind of wrapper?) that you'll need to bypass.  As far as Perforce itself goes, `p4 submit -d` is the solution.

Comment: hmmm.. I think there is definitely some wrapper in between, which needs this prompt, and if I do not provide this, the submission fails entirely.  Sorry I'm pretty new to perforce.

Comment: Also checked the submit option of p4 and following is the description I found.

-d description
Immediately submit the default changelist with the description supplied on the command line, and bypass the interactive form. This option is useful when scripting, but does not allow for jobs to be added, nor for the default changelist to be modified.

Comment: Your original question didn't mention jobs -- look at the `p4 fix` command.  :)   
 Easiest thing is to submit your change and then add the jobs to it since `fix` doesn't require any sort of prompting.  Can't help you with the wrapper since that's not a Perforce thing as far as I know; I'd recommend talking to your IT department.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Sam, Let me check this out.